# How to redirect a url with a parameter to a custom 404 page?

Tags: http-status-code-404

I have hundreds of bad URLs. They all have a parameter in common 
i.g parmameter "date"

I've tried this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^ date=(.+?)
RewriteRule ^$ http://domain.com/404 $ [R,L]
```

The result was that it redirect to a non-existing page and resulted a 404 error

I've also tried

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^ date=(.+?)
RewriteRule . - http://domain.com/404 [R=404,L]
```

The result was a 404 but not my own custom 404 page

How to redirect a url with a parameter to a custom 404 page?

Answer (score 1):

If you have your own custom 404 that always should be displayed when the page can't be found, I would suggest changing that in your virtual host:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /pathtofile
```

Or via htaccess.

```
ErrorDocument 404 /pathtofile
```

If you would like to redirect based upon date parameter, this should do:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} date
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ 404.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

Hope this helps, if it does don't forget to check and up vote ;)